# Android Download From URL in Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, download

I am using the following code for Download files from URL:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                URL url = new URL(address);
                Log.i("URL:",address);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(sockettimeout);
                int filesize = connection.getContentLength();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outputStream =new FileOutputStream(path);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2*1024];
                int length = 0 ;
                downloadedSize = 0;
                while((length = inputStream.read(buffer))>0){

                    outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
                    downloadedSize += length;
                    Log.i("downloaded Size",""+downloadedSize);

                    listener.onDownloadPercentListener((downloadedSize*100)/filesize);

                    if(downlaodedSize == filesize){
                        listener.onDownloadCompleteListener();
                    }   
                } 
           }
    });
     thread.start();
```

Although my files downloading completely , but the value of downloadedSize **field** always is zero and listener can't be executed .
another question is that why i can't using downloadedSize variable as a **local** variable and it doesn't have visibility in **while loop**?

Comment: hmm, first i'm pretty sure that this is not an exact code that you are using(where downloadedSize field is zero?) ...  second ... why don't you just put `listener.onDownloadCompleteListener();` after while loop? ... *as a local variable* where? it can be local in fx `run` scope ... please read java basics about: variable scopes and anonymous classes

Comment: thank you @Selvin , i put listener after while loop and problem solved. sorry for stupid question :))

Comment: You can write about your solution in the answer box provided and then accept your won answer. This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.